# Square using define directive not working

Tags: c, perfect-square

I implemented a squaring define directive as this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SQR(y) ((y)*(y))

int main() {
    int a;
    printf("Enter : ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    a = SQR(a);
    printf("The square is: %d\n",SQR(a));
    return 0;
}
```

But when I execute it, I don't get any error, but it is giving wrong answer every time.

Why is it giving 4th power instead of second power of input?

Comment: Now I wonder why `Doomsday is near` :S

Comment: "*But when i execute it, I dont get any error*" So why do you have the tags [tag:compiler-errors] and [tag:runtime-error]?

Comment: World gonna destroy exponentially. `#Doomsday is near`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are squaring it twice.**

In your code:

```
a = SQR(a);
printf("The square is: %d\n",SQR(a));
```

1. this first makes `a = a*a`
2. Now you print `SQR((a*a)*(a*a))`, or `a*a*a*a`

You can replace `SQR(a)` in `printf` with a, **or** 
remove the `a = SQR(a)`

Try this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SQR(y) ((y)*(y))

int main() {
    int a;
    printf("Enter : ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("The square is: %d\n",SQR(a));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are writig `((a)*(a))` twice in your code.

`a = SQR(a);    //<-- Here a = a*a
  printf("The square is: %d\n",SQR(a));    //<-- and here print a*a`

Answer (score 0):

You calculate the square two times. You first square `a` here:

```
a = SQR(a);
```

and then, square this number again in the `printf`:

```
printf("The square is: %d\n",SQR(a));
```

Fix the problem by replacing the above `printf` with:

```
printf("The square is: %d\n", a);
```

Comment: @weston I get red dialog box which reads : "Requires 15 reputation"

Comment: @Doomsday666 sorry, I didn't know/remember there was a limit

Answer (score 0):

you are misunderstanding the usage of **c macro**.

There is no issue with your macro definition. The issue is with the usage.

```
a = SQR(a);
```

In above line, you calculate the square of `a` and assign result to `a` again. So after above line execute the value of `a` is square of input value.

Then again in below line, you are calling macro on `a`.

```
printf("The square is: %d\n",SQR(a));
```

Then you prints the square of the current value of `a`. That value is not wt you need to get.

For example, if you input 2, you will get 16, but you need 4 as the answer.